# How to use try catch for function errors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, try-catch

I am doing a validation for certain objects. This code validated certain by the keyN of validationRule and validateObj.

I need to Implement a try catch to log whenever there is an error and when the value is not matched.

```
function validationKey(keyN) {
  var valObj = window.config.validationRule;
  if (typeof(validateObj[keyN]) != 'undifined') {
    for (i = 0; i < validateObj[keyN].validationTypes[i] {
        switch (validateObj[keyN].validationTypes[i]) {
          case (dataType):
            if (typeof(_dl[keyN]) == validateObj[keyN].exceptionDataType) {
              console.log(keyN + "..value matched");
            } else {
              console.log(keyN + "..is not matched");
            }

            break;

          case ('length'):
            if (_dl[keyN].length != validateObj[keyN].exceptionLength) {
              console.log(keyN + "..value matched");
            } else {
              console.log(keyN + "..is not matched");
            }

            break;
          default:
            console.log(_dl[keyN] + "..not validated as no rule defined");

        }
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log("No validation Object available");

    }
```

I used this a try-catch as below. It doesn't give any output

```
try {
  validationKey(keyN);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Unless validationKey actually has some error like use of undefined variable your catch won't be triggered unless you explicitly do a `throw error`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `validateObj` instead of `valObj`. So change it like below -

```
var validateObj = window.config.validationRule;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "throw" an error when you run into a mismatch.

```
throw new Error("Description for mismatch");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few typo in your code. (For example the for loop is not well constructed, using validateObj instead of valObj and you should give a valid argument to your function in the try-catch block.) Try this:

```
function validationKey(keyN) {
var valObj = window.config.validationRule;
  if (typeof valObj[keyN] != 'undifined') {
    for (i = 0; i < valObj[keyN].validationTypes[i]; i++) {
      switch (valObj[keyN].validationTypes[i]) {
        case dataType:
          if (typeof _dl[keyN] == validateObj[keyN].exceptionDataType) {
            console.log(keyN + '..value matched');
          } else {
            console.log(keyN + '..is not matched');
          }

        break;

        case 'length':
          if (_dl[keyN].length != validateObj[keyN].exceptionLength) {
            console.log(keyN + '..value matched');
          } else {
            console.log(keyN + '..is not matched');
          }

          break;
          default:
            console.log(_dl[keyN] + '..not validated as no rule defined');
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No validation Object available');
    }
  }  

try {
  validationKey('1');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```